# Convert specific eregi_replace to preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

I know this isn't exactly a new issue, but I'm not an expert on the preg_replace function. I have once found this code on the internet to turn URL etc. into clickable links, but since PHP 5.3 I get a "deprecated" notification and don't know how to fix it... I've tried adding the / delimiter, but without success. Any ideas?

```
function clickLinks($sText) {
 $sText = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)',
 '<a href="\1" target="_blank"><font color="black">\1</font></a>', $sText);
 $sText = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)',
 '\1<a href="http://\2" target="_blank"><font color="black">\2</font></a>', $sText);
 $sText = eregi_replace('([_.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+.)+[a-z]{2,3})',
 '<a href="mailto:\1"><font color="black">\1</font></a>', $sText);
return $sText;
}
```

Comment: Gazillions of examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But to help.  Just add delimeters to the begining and end of the pattern, I used # and escape any delimiters that are in the pattern with \ so the engine knows its not a delimeter, so \#:

```
$sText = preg_replace('#(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~\#?&//=]+)#',
 '<a href="\1" target="_blank"><font color="black">\1</font></a>', $sText);
```

Comment: Just noticed the //= in the char class, why two /?

Comment: Don't know why, just copied the code from the web and it did the job... Many thanks for your help! Changed the rest of the code accordingly and it works perfectly again!

Comment: Hmm, `(f|ht){1}tp` is rather strained, imo. Would `(ftp|http)` be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

the main diference between eregi and preg are preg is based on regex of perl, eregi regex of unix and preg_* functions must start with a delemiter, like '/'

```
$regex  = '/[a-z]/'; 
preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $string)
```

[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)